# How to translate numbers in django translation?

Tags: django, django-templates, translation

My head could not click how to translate numbers in `django translation`. It is not possible to translate by `string id`. I could print `2020` like:

```
{% translate '2' %}{% translate '0' %}{% translate '2' %}{% translate '0' %}
```

Obvioulsy, It is not the way. So, I am missing something. I would want something like:

```
{% translate "2020"|number %} # May be ?? It should be that easy right?
```

It should be that, translation from `0` to `9`.

Comment: what is the point of *translating* a ***number***?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Okay... `1` in english is `१` in my language. So, I want to translate language basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't have this functionality (yet), but you can achieve the same by creating a custom template tag. You can read the whole documentation of creating the tag here, [**Custom template tags and filters**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters).

By this way, you can translate [*Arabic Numerals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) (or anything) to any form, all you need is a ***mapper dict*** and a function that converts things by using the ***mapper dict***.

We need to have a dict that has the source numerals as keys and target numeral as values. In this case, I assume you need to translate from [*Arabic numerals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals)  to [*nepali numerals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_in_Nepali_language)

So, I have created a *simple* mapper using `dict` and converted the receiving value to something else using the **`translate_nepal_numeral(...)`** function.

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

NUMBER_MAP = {
    "0": "०",
    "1": "१",
    "2": "२",
    # and so on

}

register = template.Library()


@register.filter()
@stringfilter
def translate_nepal_numeral(value):
    try:
        return "".join([NUMBER_MAP[char] for char in value])
    except KeyError:
        return value
```

Then in your template,

```
{% load custom_numerals %}

{{ "2010"|translate_nepal_numeral }}
```

#### Examples

```
In [3]: translate_nepal_numeral("2020")
Out[3]: '२०२०'

In [4]: translate_nepal_numeral("2120")
Out[4]: '२१२०'

In [5]: translate_nepal_numeral("2120a")
Out[5]: '2120a'
```

#### Notes

1. If you are passing a non-numeral, this function will return the input

Comment: Oh!!! Okay this makes sense. I will let you know after I could apply it on my system.

Comment: Okay. It is working but, `customtags` does not take request right? So, I have to check the current language and only make translation. For that, I have to pass another argument as current code from template. Is there anything we can do??

Comment: I think it will work but, I don't think this is still the best way. Let's see what other people have to say.

Comment: *"I don't think this is still the best way"* , What is something ideal in this situation, ***in your opinion***?

Comment: BTW, the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.defaultfilters.stringfilter) itself states that, *"If you’re writing a template filter that only expects a string as the first argument, you should use the decorator `stringfilter`. This will convert an object to its string value before being passed to your function"*

Comment: I have to do `{% get_languages as LANG_CODE %}` and `{{ "2010"|number_translator:LANG_CODE }}` so much, that is why I didn't think it is the ideal way. **In my opinion it should not be that repetetive**.

Comment: That's also a good option. But, I wouldn't prefer that unless you have some numeral datasets, for only one language, the code creating a mess. BTW, I have rollback your edit since it wipes the simple solution to the problem. You can add the ***generic version*** of the solution by appending the answer.